# Create system version table that tracks schema changes

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I was recently experimenting with this feature and it works well but I expected schema changes too be saved.

Is there any way to achieve the following?

```
CREATE table test (id INT NOT NULL, field_1 VARCHAR(10)) ENGINE=InnoDB;

ALTER TABLE test ADD SYSTEM VERSIONING;

INSERT INTO test (id, field_1) VALUES (1, "test");

SELECT NOW(); -> 2022-02-03 22:48:56

ALTER TABLE test DROP COLUMN field_1;

SELECT NOW(); -> 2022-02-03 22:58:56

SELECT * FROM test FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP '2022-02-03 22:48:56';
```

```
+----+---------+
| id | field_3 |
+----+---------+
|  1 | test    |
+----+---------+
```

```
SELECT * FROM test FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP '2022-02-03 22:58:56';
```

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
```

I am aware that there may be a penalty in terms of storage size but is there any way to achieve a complete history including schema changes with MariaDB/mysql. If not is there any other database where this would work?

Comment: System versioning is specifically for data, tracking schema changes is something you either have to implement yourself but typically is part of a source-control solution.

Answer (score 1):

SQL database definitions that roll forward and roll back in time -- a longstanding dream of many who develop database apps!

Alas, it is not present in system-versioned tables. Yet.

Memory (RAM and SSD) is getting cheap enough that this might be possible. Virtual machine snapsnot tech might be part of the answer.

MariaDB has a fairly robust database server to storage engine interface. One could clone InnoDB and make a storage engine with a time dimension to it.

Somebody is going to do this. It could be you.

Comment: I agree, and with many enterprise systems, or in a cloud managed solution like AWS RDS, it is common practice to make snapshots using the features of a NAS like Netapp.  I have worked at companies in my career that had a NETAPP backed SAN which used snapshots to solve a number of problems that traditionally would be time consuming with a large database.   We used snapshots prior to the rollout of any new feature release of our services, as well as using them for disaster recover archiving, backups and copying to stage.  With any really large db, these are impractically lengthy tasks.

Comment: A dream? I don't see any use case for that feature (except that you fired a DML statement by mistake - and for fixing that you can use snapshots and/or binlog)

Comment: I have a client that wants a replicated read only slave database for them to query at will, I don't want any control of their server because I would need to maintain it. There is no chance my client could touch binlog / snapshots. I also want to be able to change the schema of master server at will which should automatically push changes to the slave. This is a use case that saves me time, I don't care if there is a storage factor cost. Also the client is in banking so they care about temporal integrity of their data.